# mysql where + group by very slow

Tags: mysql, group-by, key

one question that I should be able to answer myself but I don't and I also don't find any answer in google:

I have a table that contains 5 million rows with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files_history2` (
  `FILES_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_FROM` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_TO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ON_HOLD` decimal(1,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DIVISION_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `DATE_FROM` (`DATE_FROM`),
  KEY `FILES_ID` (`FILES_ID`),
  KEY `CAMPAIGN_ID` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`),
  KEY `CAMP_DATE` (`CAMPAIGN_ID`,`DATE_FROM`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I execute

```
SELECT files_id, min( date_from )
FROM files_history2
WHERE campaign_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY files_id
```

the query rests with status "Sending data" for more than eight hours (then I killed the process).

Here the explain:

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys           key     key_len     ref     rows        Extra
1   SIMPLE          files_history2  ALL     CAMPAIGN_ID,CAMP_DATE   NULL    NULL        NULL    5073254     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I assume that I generated the necessary keys but then the query should take that long, does it?

Comment: Does that say `5073254` rows? Try throwing a limit on there.

Comment: shouldn't be nearly that bad. indexes are intended to help speed up queries. must be something else at play. possibly a mis-configuration, starving mysql of memory.

Comment: It's going to `filesort` instead of using any of the indexes. There's a reason for that, but unfortunately I'm not smart enough to see it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a different index... Index on (Files_ID, Date_From, Campaign_ID)...

Since your group by is on Files_ID, you want THOSE grouped.  Then the MIN( Date_From), so that is in second position...  Then FINALLY the Campaign_ID to qualify for not null and here's why...

If you put all your campaign IDs first, great, get all the NULLs out of the way... Now, you have 1,000 campaigns and the Files_ID spans MANY campaigns and they also span many dates, you are going to choke.

By the index I'm projecting, by the Files_ID first, you have each "files_id" already ordered to match your group by.  Then, within that, all the earliest dates are at the top of the indexed list... great, almost there, then, by campaign ID.  Skip over whatever NULL may be there and you are done, on to the next Files_ID

Hope this makes sense -- unless you have TONs of entries with NULL value campaigns.

Also, by having all 3 parts of the index matching the criteria and output columns of your query, it never has to go back to the raw data file for the data, it gets it all from the index directly.

Comment: works even better and after reading your explination, I see that I still have to learn a lot about MySQL . Thanks.

Comment: @holgrich, just for my knowledge of different solutions, how was final performance time as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a covering index (CAMPAIGN_ID, files_id, date_from) and check that performance.  I suspect your issue is due to the grouping not and date_from not being able to use the same index.

```
CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON files_history2 (CAMPAIGN_ID, files_id, date_from);
```

If this works you could drop the point index `CAMPAIGN_ID` as it's included in the composite index.

Answer (score 1):

Well the query is slow due to the aggregation ( function MIN ) along with grouping.
One of the solution is altering your query by moving the aggregating subquery from the WHERE clause to the FROM clause, which will be lot faster than the approach you are using.

try following:

```
SELECT f.files_id 
FROM file_history2 AS f 
JOIN ( 
SELECT campaign_id, MIN(date_from) AS datefrom 
FROM file_history2 
GROUP BY files_id 
) AS f1 ON f.campaign_id = f1.campaign_id AND f.date_from = f1.datefrom;
```

This should have lot better performance, if doesn't work temporary table would only be the choice to go with.

Comment: I don't understand where the "campaign_id IS NOT NULL" is included in your statement. I make sure that I correctly stated my goal: for all files_id entries, there are several date_to entries with different campaign_ids. I need the oldest date_from where the campaipn_id is not null for every files_id.